# RN-42 HID: from keyboard to mouse

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, mouse, hid

I am working with an Arduino micro and RN-42 Bluetooth module. I have set the BT module as an HID keyboard by sending the commands through a terminal (using a COM port).

I want to set the device as a mouse but, now that it is in HID mode, I can't use a terminal.

How do I send the commands to set it as a mouse?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the datasheet on how to enter the command mode?

Answer (score 0):

As your device now identifies itself as an HID device, the system no longer creates a corresponding tty file. I am not sure if it is a policy (meaning it doesn't do it because it would not make sense) or a mechanism issue (meaning it's just not able to do serial communication with a device using HID profile).

All you need is a serial console. Get a USB to serial/TTL adapter, your serial adapter will have a corresponding tty file that you can open as a serial console and you will be able to output commands directly to the RN42's UART, just as you used to over Bluetooth.